# Bash, weird variable scope when populating array with results

Tags: arrays, bash, scope

I am parsing command output and putting results into array.

Works fine until exiting the inner loop - output array is empty.

```
declare -a KEYS

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
get_keys()
{

# this extracts key NAMES from log in format "timestamp keycode"
$glue_dir/get_keys $ip | while read line; do
    echo line: $line
    set -- $line # $1 timestamp $2 keycode
    echo 1: $1 2: $2
    key=(`egrep "\\s$2$" "$glue_dir/keycodes"`) # tested for matching '40' against 401, 402 etc
    set -- $key # $1 key name $2 keycode
    KEYS+=("$1")
    echo key $1
    echo KEYS inside loop: "${KEYS[@]}"
done
    echo KEYS outside loop: "${KEYS[@]}"
}
```

The output when run agains two output lines:

```
line: 1270899320451 38
1: 1270899320451 2: 38
key UP
KEYS inside loop: UP
line: 1270899320956 40
1: 1270899320956 2: 40
key DOWN
KEYS inside loop: UP DOWN
KEYS outside loop:
```

I spent an hour trying to figure this out. Please help. ;-)

Comment: Thanks man, your question saved me! as well as the answer!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

When you use a pipe (`|`) to pass your command output to `while`, your `while` loop runs in a subshell. When the loop ends, your subshell terminates and your variables will not be available outside your loop.

Use [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) instead:

```
while read line; do
   # ...
done < <($glue_dir/get_keys $ip)
```

Comment: I was SO close to this solution, but failed due to the < < mark, i did 
    done <(command) instead of 
    done < <(command) ..

Thanks.

Comment: Note that you can do this in the other direction as well: `{ echo 123; echo 456; } > >(sed 's/[25]/x/')`