# Why can't I eval inside a while loop?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to create bash aliases within a loop where the loop is reading lines from a command.  In order to read output line-by-line, I believe I need to pipe the output into `read`.  When I do that, however, the aliases don't exist.

If I include the following in my `.bashrc`:

```
for x in a1 a2; do
    eval "alias $x='echo foo'"
done

echo -e "a3\na4" | while read x; do
    eval "alias $x='echo foo'"
done
```

Aliases `a1` and `a2` exist, but `a3` and `a4` do not.  What is the difference between those two loops?

Comment: This is a very common gotcha when piping to a `while` loop. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612320/bash-weird-variable-scope-when-populating-array-with-results/7612420#7612420), or [BashFAQ/024](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) for details and various alternative solutions.

Comment: Also, there's no no need to use `eval` here. `alias $x='echo foo'` will expand `$x` before defining the alias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the pipeline. In a pipeline of the form `a | b | c`, each of the individual commands `a`, `b`, and `c` is run in a separate subshell [[ref](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines)], which means that it receives a copy of the parent's execution environment (including aliases), and any changes it makes to its own copy (such as by running `alias`) will have no effect on the parent [[ref](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Execution-Environment)].

In your case, you could fix this by writing:

```
while read x; do
    eval "alias $x='echo foo'"
done < <(echo -e "a3\na4")
```

which will still run `echo -e "a3\na4"` in a subshell, but will run the `while`-loop in the normal/parent execution environment.

Comment: I haven't seen the `<(command)` syntax before.  Is that creating a file descriptor pointing to the output of `command`?

Comment: @JeffKlukas: Yes; it's called "process substitution" (see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution), and it uses either a FIFO or a `/dev/fd` file. The documentation implies that it doesn't work on all systems, but it's worked on all systems I've tried, including Cygwin.

Answer (score 6):

The while loop in the pipe runs in a subshell.  You can do:

```
while read x; do
    eval "alias $x='echo foo'"
done << EOF
a3
a4 
EOF
```

Answer (score 3):

In bash 4.2 and later, you can set the `lastpipe` option to keep the *last* command of a pipe from executing in a subshell. Job control must also be off (`set +m`) for this to work.

```
shopt -s lastpipe
set +m
echo -e "a3\na4" | while read x; do
    alias $x='echo foo'
done
```